# How can we pass arguments to the main function in JAVA using command prompt and notepad?

Tags: function, cmd, arguments, program-entry-point, using

Today, I was learning about passing arguments to the main function in JAVA , with no IDE , only on Notepad and I encountered that it can only be done using command line arguments . My question is how?

Comment: The first thing I would suggest is reading the [Java documentation for command-line arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html). If you're still confused after that, update your question with code you've tried yourself that maybe didn't work or you had trouble understanding. The second thing I would suggest is having a read through the [ask] and [help] pages to learn what it takes to ask a good question for [so]. As yours stands, it is likely to be closed as there is no research effort shown on your part.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Sir, I will keep that in my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this simply by opening the cmd ,
and writing the

> javac file_name.java
>
> java file_name [set of arguments]...

suppose the program is like

```
class temp
{    
   public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        
        System.out.println(args[0]);
        System.out.println(args[1]);
       //And so on 
       // As per the length of args
     }
}
```

And if we pass

> javac temp.java
>
> java temp_name hello world

it will give output as

> hello
>
> world

Answer (score 1):

The parameter for your main method should be something like `String[] args`, right?  Its just an array of Strings.  When you run your program from the commandline, the java executable looks at all the arguments passed in after the file name and appends them to the `args` variable.

For example, take this program that takes two arguments and sums them:

```
public class Adder
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int one = (int) args[0];
        int two = (int) args[1];
        System.out.println(one + two);
    }
}
```

You'd call this by doing something like `C:\> java Adder 15 23`, and it would print out `38`.

Notice that it reads them all as Strings, so you have to cast them to whatever variable type you need.