# what arguments should i pass in this program so as to avoid java.lang error?

Tags: java, indexing, arguments, syntax-error, lang

This is the prog i was trying to run :

```
public class RightTriangle {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int a = Integer.*parseInt*(args[0]); 
        int b = Integer.*parseInt*(args[1]);
        int c = Integer.*parseInt*(args[2]);
        System.out.println((c*c==a*a+b*b||b*b==a*a + c*c ||a*a == b*b + c*c)&&(c>0 && b>0 && a>0));
     }
}
```

m getting this error on running this prog on IntelliJ :--

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Users\anuavi\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=58608:C:\Users\anuavi\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\anuavi\IdeaProjects\java1\out\production\java1 RightTriangle console
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "console"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
at RightTriangle.main(RightTriangle.java:7)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

i couldn't understand why is this showing error when i copied the code from  a legitimate source??

Comment: The exception is quite clear about its cause: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "console"`. Pass valid `int`-representations as input, and the exception should go away.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31078564/how-can-we-pass-arguments-to-the-main-function-in-java-using-command-prompt-and) describes an example how to pass in the proper arguments from the command line. In your case, instead of words, you want to pass numbers; specifically, integers.

Comment: okay...but quite a beginner ..can u tell me whats a valid int representation?

Comment: @AnveK I recommend a basic tutorial on Java, e.g. [this one by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html)

Comment: @Gryphon...i tried with number..and i get the error "Index 1 length out of bound for length 1"

Answer (score 1):

What arguments are you currently passing? your application is trying to convert "console" String into a number, hence the error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "console"
```

Comment: so any number will do?like 1,2,67...?

Comment: Yes, just a number - make sure not to enter any other character.